# Is it possible to use Firebase ML kit api with ionic?

Tags: ionic3, firebase-mlkit

I would like to know if it's possible to use the Firebase ML kit with Ionic. Seems they are only allowing ios and android development but I want to see if someone is aware of a rest api or a library that allows to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, there is no official support for Ionic in ML Kit.  No immediate plans on this. We'd love to see the community take this up for now as we love different ways developers can utilize ML Kit! :)

Comment: yup I m also waiting.

Comment: I hope it happens soon !! Hate to build native app just for it :D

Comment: Also waiting for this

Answer (score 1):

It is possible indeed. You can always develop the "native" plugin to interact with the native API and invoke it from ionic using [cordova exec](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html#javascript).

This said, I understand from your question you're expecting directly a plugin to interact with FireBase ML. There are some initiatives already being developed like: https://github.com/paulstelzer/cordova-plugin-ml-kit

This will allow you to just include the plugin and interact with it's API directly to get the Firebase ML capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I started developing a plugin to interact with Firebase ML Kit, you can find it on following link: [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-ml-kit).

It uses cordova exec and it is built based on the cordova plugin from paulstelzer, but with added features.

For now you can use it for Text Recognition and Image Labelling.

Plugin allows you to just include the plugin and interact with it's API directly to get the Firebase ML capabilities.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).